# How to extract DDL from database and write each DDL to a location in your directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, hive, sh

How to extract DDL from database and write each DDL to a location in your directory AS ITS OWN FILE. Automatically, each DDLs should be wrote as [table_name].sql.

So for example:

- Input: All the tables in the database
- Output file(s): table1.sql , table2.sql, etc. All separate files in a location in my directory.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
hiveDBName=abc_db;

showcreate="show create table "
showpartitions="show partitions "
terminate=";"

tables=`hive -e "use $hiveDBName;show tables;"`
tab_list=`echo "${tables}"`

 rm -f ${hiveDBName}_all_table_partition_DDL.txt

for list in $tab_list
do
   showcreatetable=${showcreatetable}${showcreate}${list}${terminate}
   listpartitions= `hive -e "use $hiveDBName; ${showpartitions}${list}"` 

   for tablepart in $listpartitions
   do
      partname=`echo ${tablepart/=/=\"}`
      echo $partname
      echo "ALTER TABLE $list ADD PARTITION ($partname\");" >> ${hiveDBName}_all_table_partition_DDL.txt
   done

done

echo " ====== Create Tables ======= : " $showcreatetable

## Remove the file
rm -f ${hiveDBName}_extract_all_tables.txt

hive -e "use $hiveDBName; ${showcreatetable}" >> ${hiveDBName}_extract_all_tables.txt
```

The problem is, whenever I run this, it puts all the DDLS created in ONE file. I want each DDL to be its own file with its table name as the file name: [table name].sql.

Any ideas or suggestion to correct my code above?

Comment: The assignment `showcreatetable=${showcreatetable}${showcreate}${list}${terminate}` is playing with fire.  IMO, you should use quotes around the RHS: `showcreatetable="${showcreatetable}${showcreate}${list}${terminate}"`.  You should probably use the `$(cmd …)` notation instead of back-ticks, too.

Comment: Also, in ```listpartitions= `hive -e "use $hiveDBName; ${showpartitions}${list}"` ```, you do not want the space after the equals sign.

Comment: If you want the schema for each table in a separate file, you'll need to generate one file per table, inside the loop, rather than accumulating all the 'create table' operations into a single monster command string.  You'll redirect based on the name in `$list` (`>$list.sql` or thereabouts).